# Python script runs slower on google compute instance as compared with colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-compute-engine, google-colaboratory

Why is my machine learning python/tensorflow script runs faster on colab as compared with a 24-vCPU google compute instance?

Invocation on colab: `!/content/myscript.py`

Invocation on google compute instance: `!/home/prj1/myscript.py`

epoch time on colab: 0.8 s

epoch time on google compute instance: 2.0 s

In both cases, I am using tensorflow 1.11 and python 2.7, myscript.py is the only program running, and GPU is not being used. The script displays training progress (text-only, no graphics) on the screen every 10 epochs.

Comment: Can you share the script?

Comment: I apologize David, but at this stage, I cannot share the script.

Comment: Which GCE image had you used with the regular 24CPU machine?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Colaboratory is optimized for Tensorflow, while a GCE instance is 
a regular machine. ["When you create a new notebook on colab.research.google.com, TensorFlow is already pre-installed and optimized for the hardware being used."](https://medium.com/tensorflow/colab-an-easy-way-to-learn-and-use-tensorflow-d74d1686e309) This is likely why you are seeing a performance difference between the two.

Comment: I was hoping that the software supported by GCE instance is optimized for them. I will now try to install Google's "Preconfigured VMs for deep learning applications" images and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Google provides "Click to deploy" [deep learning VM images](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/) that are optimized for machine learning. [Cloud Machine Learning Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) is also available as an optimized solution.

Comment: Also, [Cloud TPUs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus) are ASICs available on the platform that have been made specifically to be the most optimal tool for Tensor Flow.

Comment: I have tried a Google's "Click to deploy"VM image, tf-latest-cpu to be more specific. I am trying to run several deep learning python/tensorflow scripts on a 32 vCPU Google compute instance. For some reason, all the python/tensorflow scripts are being run on two of the 32 vCPUs (vCPU #0 and #16) when I use that image.

I have tried the same setup using the standard Google compute instance image. In that case, load was evenly distributed among the vCPUs. I am trying the tf-latest-cpu image to speed things up.

Comment: Using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) sample python script, we were able to test this behaviour. We found all CPU cores were utilized for both instances. The standard instance took 1 minute 19 seconds, while the TensorFlow image took 1 minute 2 seconds to complete. The article you've found seems to be a feasible work around.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bring the epoch time down to 1.1 s by following the optimization recommended at [Tips to Improve Performance for Popular Deep Learning Frameworks on CPUs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/tips-to-improve-performance-for-popular-deep-learning-frameworks-on-multi-core-cpus)

Here is the code:

```
import os
N_CORES                       = int(os.cpu_count()/2)
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = str(N_CORES)
os.environ["KMP_BLOCKTIME"]   = "30"
os.environ["KMP_SETTINGS"]    = "1"
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"]    = "granularity=fine,verbose,compact,1,0"
config_sess                   = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=N_CORES, inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, allow_soft_placement=True, device_count = {'CPU': N_CORES})

with tf.Session(config=config_sess) as sess:
```